# Switch between two different MySQL queries based on the parameter value

Tags: mysql, case

I have a user controlled parameter which I have named as @param here.It  decides which query to execute. If it's set to A , then rows need to be fetched from table A ( **I want multiple rows and columns to be returned** ). If it's set to any thing else fetch the data from table B. So far I have tried the following query :

```
@param = "A"

SELECT 
CASE WHEN @param = "A"
THEN
     (SELECT * FROM table_A)
ELSE
     (SELECT * FROM table_B)
END
```

but it returns me the following error :

```
Error Code: 1241
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Please suggest how can I accomplish the task requirements i.e **switch between two different queries based on the parameter value**.

Comment: Are you trying to write a stored procedure? What language is your application written in?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm actually using pentaho community dashboard editor. All it alows me is to add an sql query for data source.